# How would you balance load on multiple *dynamic* backend Instances of Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture, scalability, backend, software-design

I'm relatively new to StackOverflow and not sure if it's appropriate place to ask design question. Site gives me a hint *"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"*. Perhaps it should be asked on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Please let me know.

Anyway.. One of the projects I'm working on is online survey engine. It's my first big commercial project on [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/).

I need your advice on how to collect stats and efficiently record them in DataStore without bankrupting me. Initial requirements are:

- After user finishes survey client sends list of pairs [ID (int) + PercentHit (double)]. This list shows how close answers of this user match predefined answers of reference answerers (which identified by IDs). I call them "target IDs".
- Creator of the survey wants to see aggregated % for given IDs for last hour, particular timeframe or from the beginning of the survey.
- Some surveys may have thousands of target/reference answerers.

So I created entity

```
public class HitsStatsDO implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    transient private Long id;
    transient private Long version = (long) 0;

    transient private Long startDate;

    @Parent transient private Key parent;   // fake parent which contains target id
    @Transient int targetId;

    private double avgPercent;
    private long hitCount;
}
```

But writing HitsStatsDO for each target from each user would give a lot of data. For instance I had a survey with 3000 targets which was answered by ~4 million people within one week with 300K people taking survey in first day. Even if we assume they were answering it evenly for 24 hours it would give us ~1040 writes/second. Obviously it hits concurrent writes limit of Datastore.

I decided I'll collect data for one hour and save that, that's why there are `avgPercent` and `hitCount` in `HitsStatsDO`. GAE instances are stateless so I had to use [dynamic backend instance](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/).

There I have something like this:

```
// Contains stats for one hour
private class Shard
{
    ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    Map<Integer, HitsStatsDO> map = new HashMap<Integer, HitsStatsDO>(); // Key is target ID

    public void saveToDatastore();
    public void updateStats(Long startDate, Map<Integer, Double> hits);
}
```

and map with shard for current hour and previous hour (which doesn't stay here for long)

```
private HashMap<Long, Shard> shards = new HashMap<Long, Shard>();   // Key is HitsStatsDO.startDate
```

So once per hour I dump Shard for previous hour to Datastore.

Plus I have `class LifetimeStats` which keeps `Map<Integer, HitsStatsDO>` in memcached where map-key is target ID.

Also in my [backend shutdown hook method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/LifecycleManager.html#setShutdownHook%28com.google.appengine.api.LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook%29) I dump stats for unfinished hour to Datastore.

There is only one major issue here - **I have only ONE backend instance** :) It raises following questions on which I'd like to hear your opinion:

- Can I do this without using backend instance ?
- What if one instance is not enough ?
- How can I split data between multiple *dynamic* backend instances? It hard because I don't know how many I have because Google creates new one as load increases.
- I know I can launch exact number of *resident* backend instances. But how many ? 2, 5, 10 ? What if I have no load at all for a week. Constantly running 10 backend instances is too expensive.
- What do I do with data from clients while backend instance is dead/restarting?

One thing to note is that I can't change client much. Currently it's JavaScript embedded into web-pages of customers. I can change RPC in some way but architecturally I cannot replace client with Google Docs forms for example.

Thank you very much in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My service went live and I want to share how I implemented it.

So instead of gathering data in memory of single backend instance for an hour I decided to gather it in multiple dynamic backend instances and update shard for current hour in Datastore every 10 mins from each instance. Class `Shard` stays the same with the exception of `saveToDatastore()` where I now update `HitsStatsDOs` in transaction loop to make sure it's updated even if another backend instance changes shard at the moment.

In order to fetch HitsStatsDO really fast I decided to put target ID in fake parent key and timestamp if this hard to primary ID like this

```
public class HitsStatsDO implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    transient private Long id;  // always equals to "startDate"
    @Unindexed
    transient private Long version = (long) 0;

    transient private Long startDate;

    @Parent
    transient private Key targetIdKey;   // fake parent which contains target id

    @Unindexed
    private double avgPercent;
    @Unindexed
    private long hitCount;

    public Key<HitsStatsDO> createKey()
    {
        return new Key<HitsStatsDO>(targetIdKey, HitsStatsDO.class, startDate);
    }

    public HitsStatsDO(Long startDate, long targetId)
    {
        this.id = this.startDate = startDate;
        this.targetIdKey = new Key(Long.class, targetId);
    }
}
```

This entity takes only 2 writes to be stored. Amount of writes is never more than ([amount of backend instances] * 2 * 6) per hour which is not bad. Also I can pre-create keys in my code and do batch-get from Datastore.

Similarly I changed `HitsStatsTotalDO` which contains stats from the beginning of survey. It looks like this

```
public class HitsStatsTotalDO implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private Long targetId;
    @Unindexed
    transient private Long version = (long) 0;

    @Unindexed
    private double avgPercent;
    @Unindexed
    private long hitCount;
}
```

Same thing - 2 writes to store/update.

Service went live 3 days ago. Maximum load so far was 230 QPS. I'm using dynamic B1 type instances. In config I set maximum of 4 instances for now but to my pleasure GAE never instantiated more than one. And surprisingly I haven't had concurrency exceptions yet.

Let me know if you have any questions or think I missed something.

And thank you everyone for your help. StackOverflow is really awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

Developers should not shy away from integrating offline resources, google sites and google data api with gae.

You could set up a google site which leads to your survey form.

Target respondents would enter their answers into your form, and google sites collects them in a single google docs spreadsheet.

You then use an off-line system (not gae) that accesses that "spreadsheet" thro google data api periodically/hourly to download the data.

Google docs would provide you the time of data entry, while your form design should be able allow indexing by respondents. In that way, you will be able to download only segments of the "spreadsheet".

You will need to acquire familiarity with OAuth, and perhaps, google federated login/openid consumer.

You could explore integrating the respondent's login with your form.

In fact, you may not even have to use gae.

You should be able to use google sites api to update your pages, updating the statistics to be displayed, to switch the form to a new spreadsheet.

And then use gae only for generating user specific pages.

Alternatively, if you have too great an afinity for gae, you could use it to generate survey pages and then using data api to store the results in google docs, but use your own offline resources to perform the statistical computing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Unfortunately I can't change client that drastically. I should have mentioned it in the original post. I updated it. Thanks again!

Comment: "A docs form isn't going to scale to a million respondents" - is that what Google says? Like a google blog page would not scale to a million readers? Remember, anonymous failed to bring down Amazon. Will a million users bring down a google page?

Comment: I added my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you encounter concurrent write limits on the model you describe is because you're making all the instances child entities of the same parent. This is only necessary if you need entities in the same entity group for transactional purposes, which is not the case here. Remove the parent property and store all entities as top-level ones, and you will no longer have to worry about update rates.

Comment: Let me do rough calculation on cost. So I guess I'll have 6 write ops per entity (2 for entity + 2 for index of targetId + 2 for index of timestamp). Then survey with 3k targets and 4M users will give me 12'000'000'000 new HitsStatsDO entities. That's 72B writes ($0.1/100K) + 12B smalls ($0.01/100K) which is $72K + $1200 respectively. $73.2K is pretty harsh price for one popular survey :(

Comment: @ruslan What are "3k targets" in this context?

Comment: Those are reference answers to which users' answers are compared to. For example it might be survey about political/social/economics preferences. 3000 politicians took the survey. Then public takes the survey too. Now you can see which candidate is closer to views of majority. More simple example is Sunglasses online store. You don't know what you want to buy. You answer 10 questions, it gives you what sunglasses are the best for you. Something like that :)

Comment: @ruslan Why do you need to store data for every combination of user response and 'target', then? Just store the user's responses, and at the end, compute whatever analytics/reports you need.

Comment: More expensive than storing O(n*m) records? That seems unlikely. :)

Comment: So currently each answer requires 2 writes only. But fetching them all for reporting purposes would be pricy.

Comment: @ruslan Currently each answer requires 2 writes, plus at least 2 writes per 'target'. That's definitely going to be more expensive than fetching each answer once to do reporting.

Comment: Actually Answer class has no indexed fields right now. It has parent key that points to User class. So I guess it uses only 2 writes per answer. What do you think if I use Push Queues to prevent loss of data when backend instance restarting ? I'm still limited by one backend instance though :( Can't come up with optimal solution for that.

Comment: I added my answer to this question.

Comment: @ruslan You still haven't explained why you think you need to store a record for every combination of user and 'target'. You really don't.

Comment: I don't. I store aggregated value of average % for each hour which is calculated from "hitsCouts" users.